# Disable elements from been sent on form submission

Tags: jquery, serialization, textbox, radio-button

I'm using [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
in order to submit my form elements. I have some radio buttons that are used to enable some text boxes if needed (something like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/9CDcH/2/)). However, the radio buttons are submitted as well, even though they are used only to enable text areas.

Is there an option to disable them from been sent once the form is submitted?

The following code is just an example to my radio button:

```js
$('.RadioExample').not('.First').siblings().prop('disabled',true);

$('.RadioExample').on('click',function(){
    $('.RadioExample')
        .siblings()
        .prop('disabled',true);
    
    $(this)
        .siblings()
        .prop('disabled',false);
});
```

```css
#first {
    background-color: red;
}

#second {
    background-color: green;
}

#third {
    background-color: yellow;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Control fields</h1>
<div id="content">
    <div id="first">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" class="RadioExample First" checked="checked" />First</br>
            <input type="text" id="txt_one" /></br>
            <input type="text" id="txt_two" /></br>
    </div>
<div id="second">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" class="RadioExample" />Second</br>
<input type="text" id="three" /></br>
          <input type="text" id="txt_four" /></br>
    </div>

    <div id="third">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio3" class="RadioExample" />Third</br>
            <input type="text" id="txt_five" /></br>
            <input type="text" id="txt_six" /></br>
            <input type="text" id="txt_seven" /></br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: before `serialize()` `disable` the radio buttons using `jQuery` as well

Comment: @shu Thanks. That's an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not `find` the elements inside the form and exclude radios using `not`

```
$('#formID').find('input').not("input[type='radio']").serialize()
```